# интерпретатор. string to char не работает

Tags: java, строки, char, конвертация, интерпретатор

Делаю что-то вроде интерпретатора. Разбиваю `String`, казалось бы, на `char[]`, и проблем не должно быть, но компилятор выдает ошибку в операторе `switch` , на этом месте case `"+"` . Ответ компилятора

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char", как понимаю он не может вставить String в char, но почему ? я же вроде как переконвертировал строку в `char` ? есть еще какие то методы конвертации более надежные? весь код такой

```
String str = "24+4*3-(6/2)";
char[] str_char = str.toCharArray();
char[] symbol = new char[10];
int[] number = new int[10];


for(int i = 0; i < str_char.length; i++)
    switch(str_char[i]) {
        case "+": symbol[0] = str_char[i]; break;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Все дело в синтаксисе.

- `"+"` - это строка (`String`) с одним символом `+`
- `'+'` - это символ (`char`) `+`

Поскольку `str_char[i]` имеет тип `char`, то в `switch` вы должны использовать второй вариант.

Comment: а вот это место  char[] str_char = str.toCharArray(); разьве не конвертирует строку в массив символов ? после чего можно  case "+": symbol[0] = str_char[i]; break;

Comment: а...все ясно, дело в скобках

Comment: Нет, дело в кавычках, а не в скобках. Терминология важна, чтобы понимать других членов сообщества. Иначе вам очень трудно будет искать ответы на свои вопросы, и, например, получать помощь на SO.